# HTML5 canvas drawing line over ruler

Tags: html, jquery-plugins, html5-canvas

Please visit the following jsfiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/mayanknimje87/GfaZ2/3/

there is a ruler and pencil. I can draw line over ruler when it is straight. But when i rotate the scale, drawing of line won't work. Also, i want to give animation, when user put pencil over the ruler (restrict to upper portion of ruler only not to bottom or middle),It start drawing line and animate. Ex. If user put pencil on ruler mark 15 then it should animate and draw line from 15 to 0 . Also user can draw line when pencil touches the top of ruler not in middle and bottom. Please help me out. It will be great to learn. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is something i found for animation using css3 -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
But don't no how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the canvas pixels to be drawn above those image elements, you will have to put the canvas on top.  However, the canvas will then soak up the mouse events.

Still, I think you should do that, and then catch the mouse events in the canvas and handle the dragging there.

Comment: I did the same, please can you check that jsfiddle. Line is drawn over the ruler only when ruler is straight. When i rotate the ruler, pencil won't draw line.

Comment: I do not see that behavior.  I see the canvas is behind the images, I confirmed that in webkit inspector.  I dragged the pencil without touching the ruler.  The line was drawn _under_ the ruler.  I'm using Chrome 15.0.874.121 m on Windows 7.

Comment: However, I do see the behavior that if the ruler is first rotated, then dragging the pencil does not produce a line.  I think this has to do with your use of draggable/droppable, with which I am not familiar.  Perhaps you should try handling the pencil drag in mousemove, like you handle the ruler rotate.

Comment: Hi, I Tried all possible way but not found the solution.
Please if any one can help me out its very urgent. Already crosses the deadline. Please experts help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: HI, i found a bug.Please try this and give me some solution. Try doing this is firefox , start inspect element there select ruler image you can see your image is highlighted. Now rotate the scale and again check the inspect element. You can see that Image visible to user is rotated but when you inspect, it is in same state. I think it is a box-shadow problem. Please any one had any solution.

Comment: Can Anyone one have solution.

Comment: @Mayank N: I do not understand your current problem.  Are you concerned about the way firebug draws a blue rectangle over the original space of the ruler when the ruler element is selected?  That does not seem important, since it doesn't affect the end-user.

Comment: Hi James, i did what you mentioned earlier but when i am creating the canvas on TOP (i.e by increasing its z-index property), nothing is movable or draggable (ie. there z-index is smaller than the canvas). Then how can i solve this problem. Please help.

Comment: Yes, because as I said the canvas will soak up the mouse events.  You now have to attach your onmousedown, onmousemove, etc. to the canvas instead of the ruler and pencil.  Then you need to figure out for yourself whether the mouse is "over" the ruler or pencil, and if so, move those parts accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time.